# display:none with required causes broken submit behaviour - how to fix?

Tags: javascript, html, css, required

I have a select tag with display:none and required both on:

There is no browser where this works properly:
IE ignores the required attribute, and submits anyway.
Firefox draws the bubble asking the user to fill in the select in the upper left corner of the page.
Chrome does nothing - the submit does not go through, as expected from required, but it does not draw its bubble anywhere.

Is there a way to get around this?  Desired behaviour is identical to when display is anything that is not none: draw the bubble asking the user to fill in the select at the select (although with display none, naturally it will appear to point at something else - typically the next visible element).

Specifically, I have a javascript-driven widget handling the multiselect ui, and it would be wonderful if the bubble could draw correctly, just pointing at the widget.

Comment: will you show some code with us? So maybe we can try to help!

Comment: Your question is unclear. Display none and required together obviously wont work as how can a user fill out a required box if it isnt displayed. So what are you trying to do?